# XQuery execution without a software

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asp-classic, xquery

How can we execute Xquery embedded inside Html or with a reference to an xquery document within html?
is there a JavaScript method ? 
or ASP DOM method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a JavaScript method ?

[No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XQuery).

> or ASP DOM method ?

[Looks like yes](http://www.pietsieg.com/articles%5Cxquery%5Cbeginner%5CUsing%20XQuery%20in%20ASP.NET%20-%20OLD%20MS%20XQuery%20Demo%5CUsing%20XQuery%20in%20ASP.NET.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Not without a third party library.

For javascript have a look at [XQIB](http://www.xqib.org/) or [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/).

For ASP.NET try [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/) or [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/) (I used to be a developer for XQSharp, and so am slightly biased).